# Mobile menu closing on click.

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using stackoverflow many times in the past to solve my coding problems, but this time I couldn't find the right answer, so I signed up and decided to ask the question myself.

TBH, I'm not very good when it comes to coding, I'm using my basic css, html and php knowledge to make some nice-looking wordpress sites for my friends.

I know the question above has been asked on here before, but I really don't know how to apply the answers I was able to find to my case.

This is the website I'm working on right now: http://serwer1652796.home.pl.

I would like the mobile menu to close when someone clicks one of the links. I know that I will probably have to use some javascript code in one of the theme's files, but what exactly should I write and in which file? (I've never had to deal with js before, so please, be understanding.)

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: I'm not sure, but here are the menu-related lines I've found in .js files.

1. bootstrap.js http://s33.postimg.org/xpm0oaxan/Zrzut_ekranu_2016_06_09_o_20_00_37.png

2. theme.js
http://s33.postimg.org/9zjpx4snj/Zrzut_ekranu_2016_06_09_o_20_01_52.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `theme.js` file, on line 260 there is code that looks like this

```
jQuery('.home #site-navigation li a[href*=#]').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll(jQuery(this.hash));
});
```

In order to close the menu, you need to add some lines to toggle some CSS classes on various items that apparently control the visibility of the menu. It should look like this afterward

```
jQuery('.home #site-navigation li a[href*=#]').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll(jQuery(this.hash));
    jQuery('#nav-toggle').toggleClass('nav-is-visible');
    jQuery('.main-navigation .onepress-menu').toggleClass("onepress-menu-mobile");
    jQuery('.header-widget').toggleClass("header-widget-mobile");
});
```

I got the extra lines to add from the events that occur when you manually close the menu via the `X` icon, which can be found in `theme.js` on lines 7, 8 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

I see your theme is using jquery. You can add something like this to the footer.php file:

```
<script>
  $(".onepress-menu li a").on("click", function() {
    $(".onepress-menu").toggleClass("onepress-menu-mobile");
  });
</script>
```

You can see the effect emulated here:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wojt200o/)