# close toggle mobile menu

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu

I want close mobile menu after click on menu item. I tried [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732923/mobile-menu-closing-on-click) codes, but no working correct.

website: www.logitrans.sk

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It appears you are new to asking questions. I encourage you to read up on the website's standards when asking questions, such as posting code, what you think the problem is, and what you have done in an attempt to solve the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

In your custom.js file look for this section:

```
$(".top_mobile_menu_wr ul.top_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children > a").on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').find('> ul').slideToggle(300);
    return false;
});
```

replace it with:

```
$(".top_mobile_menu_wr ul.top_mobile_menu li.menu-item-has-children > a").on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').find('> ul').slideToggle(300);
    $('#menu_toggle').toggleClass('open');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks. i used it, but it dont work :/ i am using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-scroll-to-id/ should it be a problem? i deactivated him, but still dont work